# Formatting text make condition between 2 words

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

Example:

> I will go to the school ***word1***

I want to make that word1 between *** bold

I want to add this condition to my script

How?

```
    history(post) {
            return post.case_history.replace(/------------------------------/g,
 '<br>------------------------------ <br>');
        }
```

Comment: Please give example of actual output. Your script is not very clear

Comment: Bold with html tags?

Comment: this is the output: ****** PHONE LOG 16.07.2018 10:35:14 belek Action Type: Incoming call ******Case Create 16.07.2018 10:36:15

Comment: Please update your question, not post comments

Comment: @SimonRi yes with HTML tags

Comment: if you're working with vue you could declare it like so in the markup: `I will go to the school <b>{{school}}</b>` where `school` is a property on your backing data object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm bad at regex but i hope this will help

```
// condition
var regex = /\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*/g;
// Get matches
while (match = regex.exec(post.case_history)) {
    // Replace *** with <b> tag   
    post.case_history = post.case_history.replace(match[0], "<b>"+match[1]+"</b>");
}
// return output
return post.case_history;
```